# MySQL syntax error with declarations

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a transaction procedure in MySQL and I keep receiving the following syntax error which is occurring in my variable declarations:

```
ERROR 1064(42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ';
DECLARE emp_duplicate INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE old_empnum INT DEFAULT 0;
DECL' at line 6
```

Below is my procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$


DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS new_employee$$

CREATE PROCEDURE new_employee(in_Fname VARCHAR(15),in_Lname VARCHAR(15),
in_hire DATE, in_DOB DATE, in_sal Numeric(7,2))

BEGIN

    DECLARE out_message VARCHAR;
    DECLARE emp_duplicate INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE old_empnum INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE out_empnum INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE time_created DATETIME;
    DECLARE user_var VARCHAR;
    DECLARE age_var Int DEFAULT 0;

    START TRANSACTION;

    Select MAX(Empno)
    Into old_empnum
    From emp;

    Select COUNT(*)
    Into emp_duplicate
    From emp
    Where (in_Fname=Fname AND in_Lname=Lname AND in_hire=HireDate AND in_DOB=DOB);

    IF emp_duplicate=0 THEN
        SET out_message = 'New employee update successful';
        SET out_empnum = old_empnum + 1;    
        SET time_created = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP();
        SET user_var = USER();
        SET age_var = DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,in_DOB);
        INSERT INTO emp(Empno,Fname,Lname,HireDate,DOB,SAL)
        VALUES(in_Fname,in_Lname,in_hire,in_DOB,in_sal);
        INSERT INTO log(Empno,DateCreated,Who)
        VALUES(out_empnum,time_created,user_var);
        SELECT out_message;
        SELECT Empno, Fname, Lname, DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE,DOB), HireDate
        From emp;
    ELSE
        SET out_message = 'Employee already exists';
        SELECT out_message;
    END IF;
    COMMIT;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I am using cmd and notepad to execute my code (just in case that's helpful).  For the life of me, I cannot see the error with my declarations?????

Answer (score 0):

you forget to datatype size for `DECLARE out_message VARCHAR (30)` and  `DECLARE user_var VARCHAR(30);`

```
DECLARE out_message VARCHAR (30); <------------- here
DECLARE emp_duplicate INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE old_empnum INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE out_empnum INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE time_created DATETIME;
DECLARE user_var VARCHAR(30);    <------------- here
DECLARE age_var Int DEFAULT 0;
```

---

In insert statement you are missing value for `Empno`

```
INSERT INTO emp(Empno,Fname,Lname,HireDate,DOB,SAL)
        VALUES(in_Fname,in_Lname,in_hire,in_DOB,in_sal);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the `VARCHAR` size like this

```
DECLARE out_message VARCHAR(20);
```

try this

```
BEGIN

    DECLARE out_message VARCHAR(20); // // varchar size here
    DECLARE emp_duplicate INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE old_empnum INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE out_empnum INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE time_created DATETIME;
    DECLARE user_var VARCHAR(20); // varchar size here
    DECLARE age_var Int DEFAULT 0;
```